# How do I disconnect a subrscribed stream from the publisher of the netstream?

Tags: apache-flex, netstream, soundcloud-stratus

I have a publisher who publishes a netstream using stratus p2p. This is then connected to by player who subscribes to the netstream.

I believe one can reject the subscriber when the stream tries to connect by using the onPeerConnect method of the netstream's client. However, I would like to boot the subscriber after they have been connected.

There are potentially other subscribers to that netstream so I cannot just close it. How would I boot a particular subscriber without closing the published netstream?

Answer (score 2):

The peerStreams property of your publishing NetStream is an array of NetStraems of all subscribers. You can iterate through it and do something like `netStream.peerStreams[0].close();`